# sshfs with different gid on remote

Tags: sshfs

I don't know how to mount a remote directory
"remote_dir" on computer "remote", having remote gid "wgrp".
Help is welcome.

```
  me@local$ sshfs me@remote:/remote_dir remote_as_wgrp ...wanted_options...
```

A workaround is to create a new user "me_wgrp" belonging to group "wgrp".
But the problem seems conceptually so simple that I'm sure there is a solution.

Context:
I'm able to connect using ssh on remote compute, and then to change my gid:

```
  me@local$ ssh me@remote
  me@remote$ newgrp wgrp
```

Now I can create files in directories which are only writable by the group "wgrp".

I have tried

```
  sshfs me@remote:/remote_dir remote_as_wgrp -o ssh_command='newgrp wgrp'
```

but sshfs seems blocked.

Also, if I try

```
  ssh me@remote 'newgrp wgrp'
```

ssh doesn't give the prompt, but it accepts commands.

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that the folder I was trying to edit was actually a symlink. I now sshfs directly to the folder (the actual real path, not following a symlink). This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ten years after the question was asked, I needed this myself.

I found that it is now possible to add a parameter to sshfs:

```
sshfs -o sftp_server="sg <group> -c '/usr/lib/misc/sftp-server -u <umask>'" ...
```

where `/usr/lib/misc/sftp-server` is the location of sftp-server on the remote system, `<group>` is the desired group on the remote system, and `-u <umask>` is an optional way of providing a default umask for the particular sftp-server.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing the default group on the remote host has newgrp will never return because it opens a new shell. 
"[newgrp](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unewgrp.htm) - return you to a prompt of a new shell."

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it looks like newgrp group, or "newgrp group -" causes sshfs to not work in the newgrp environment. You won't be able to cd into the sshfs directory or ls, basically you'll get a permission denied error (and it's not due to permissions issues). You'll also notice that df no longer shows the sshfs fuse mount.